# asp.net mvc - LINQ Query to select specific columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

the following code returns all information of table if credentials matches. But I want to write another query inside else condition block where it will return me only specific columns of admins table, for example Email, Name, and Role. How can I do that?

```
Admin adminLoggedin  = db.Admins.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email==model.Email && x.Password == model.Password);
if (adminLoggedin == null)
{
    return BadRequest();
}
else
{
    // ***Query2  select Email , Name, RoleId from Admins Where Email = adminLoggedin.Email 
    // how to write this query with Entity framework and ado.net model

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, model.RememberMe);
                        return Ok(adminLoggedin);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using anonymous type and query syntanx, you can write something like this:

```
var query = from admin in db.Admins
where admin.Email == adminLoggedIn.Email
select new { Email=admin.Email, Name=admin.Name, RoleId = admin.RoleId };
```

If you need to return this query results from this function, create a simple class with properties Name, Email etc and then use it with select clause in above query e.g.
`select new CustomClass {Email, admin.Email,}`